# Python script, make it shorter

Tags: python

How can I make this code shorter? Some code is similar and I think they can be merged into one:

```
    if not os.path.exists(".\image_1_01.bmp"):
        print('image_1_01.bmp not generated\n' 'for more info check the log file' )
        return 1
    else:
        shutil.move(".\image_1_01.bmp", output_directory)

    if not os.path.exists(".\image_1_01.raw"):
        print('image_1_01.raw not generated\n' 'for mor info check the log file' )
        return 1
    else:
        shutil.move(".\image_1_01.raw", output_directory)

    if not os.path.exists(".\image_1_01_hist.csv"):
        print('image_1_01_hist.csv not generated\n' 'for mor info check the log file' )
        return 1
    else:
        shutil.move(".\image_1_01_hist.csv", output_directory)

    if not os.path.exists(".\image_1_02.bmp"):
        print('image_1_02.bmp not generated\n' 'for more info check the log file' )
        return 1
    else:
        shutil.move(".\image_1_02.bmp", output_directory)

    if not os.path.exists(".\image_1_02.raw"):
        print('image_1_02.raw not generated\n' 'for mor info check the log file' )
        return 1
    else:
        shutil.move(".\image_1_02.raw", output_directory)

    if not os.path.exists(".\image_1_02_hist.csv"):
        print('image_1_02_hist.csv not generated\n' 'for mor info check the log file' )
        return 1
    else:
        shutil.move(".\image_1_02_hist.csv", output_directory)

    if not os.path.exists(".\scan_stats.csv"):
        print('scan_stats.csv not generated\n' 'for mor info check the log file' )
        return 1
    else:
        shutil.move(".\scan_stats.csv", output_directory)`
```

Comment: Gor, welcome to SO. However for reviews of code that works, please post on the  sister site [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: where are these hardcoded filenames coming from? are they always the same? or can they be read from an input folder? any time you repeat code, you can write a function like ```def move(filename, output_dir)```

Comment: Anyway, your code is just iteratng over a list of filenames, so use a loop `for f in [".\image_1_01.bmp", ".\image_1_01.raw", ..., ".\scan_stats.csv"]: `

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because reviews of working code belong on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

```
images = [".\image_1_01.raw",".\image_1_01_hist.csv",".\image_1_02.bmp",".\image_1_02.raw",".\image_1_02_hist.csv",".\scan_stats.csv"]

for image in images:
    if not os.path.exists(image):
        print('{} not generated\n' 'for mor info check the log file'.format(image) )
        return 1
    else:
        shutil.move(image, output_directory)
```

Comment: Reviews of code that works are off-topic on SO and should be posted on sister site [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. When a a question gets closed for being off-topic, you won't get rep for answering it.